# render Select in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select

There is no error.  The dynamic array of 18 elements seems correct then observing myCompnent in the Chromium debugger.  The question is how do you render the Select in this class and save the choice for the next props variable.

The props, which is a pure Javascript Object is being passed incorrectly to the ClusterSelection class.  An Ajax call is made to the server which passes by a list with a header and dynamic content separated by colons.  An array with keys is built and passed to the Select element creation module.

```js
class ClusterSelection extends React.Component {
  /*1*/
  constructor(props) {
    /*2*/
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      /*3*/
      theProps: this.props.value,
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: ''
    };
    /* 3 */
  }
  /* 2 */
  componentDidMount() {
    /* 2 */
    fetch("http://www.localhost:8080/johntredden-1.0/userDesignatedSubCluster.html").then(res => res.json()).then(result => {
        /* 3 */
        this.setState({
          /* 4 */
          isLoaded: true,
          items: result
        });
        /* 4 */
        // alert("items:"+ result);
      },
      /* 3 */
      // Note: it's important to handle errors here
      // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
      // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
      error => {
        /* 3 */
        this.setState({
          /* 4 */
          isLoaded: true,
          error
        });
        /* 4 */
      });
    /* 3 */
  }
  /* 2 */


  render() {
    /* 2 */
    const {
      error,
      isLoaded,
      items
    } = this.state;

    if (error) {
      return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", null, "Error: ", error.message);
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", null, "Loading cluster selection ...");
    } else {
      var response = parseJson.parseStart(this.state.items);
      var clusterTypes = response.split(':');
      var data = [];
      for(var i = 1; i < clusterTypes.length; i++){
        data.push({
          value: clusterTypes[i],
          label: clusterTypes[i]
        })
      }
      const myComponent = () => /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(Select, {
        options: data
      });

      console.log("working U and V:" + this.state.theProps.getUdim() + " " + this.state.theProps.getVdim()); // print_recursive(this.state.theProps);       

      return "u dim: " + this.state.theProps.getUdim() + "v dim: " + this.state.theProps.getVdim() + " Bulk CLusters: " + myComponent;

    }
  }
  /* 2 */
}
/* 1 */
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow. About your question, I think you might find React Docs halpful. More specifically https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag

Answer (score 0):

I believe this enclosed code is closer.  One of the problems I've encountered is all the "select" examples use a hard coded list. How to handle a dynamic list?

Here are the details on the error:

json1:SubClusters:DOUBLESTAR_BINARY_1:DOUBLESTAR_BINARY_0:THREESTAR_TRINARY_0:THREESTAR_TRINARY_2:THREESTAR_TRINARY_1:SINGLESTAR:FOURSTAR_TRINARYPLUSONE_1:FOURSTAR_TRINARYPLUSONE_TRINARY_2:FOURSTAR_TRINARYPLUSONE_TRINARY_0:FOURSTAR_TRINARYPLUSONE_TRINARY_1:FOURSTAR_2BINARIES_1_BINARY_0:FOURSTAR_2BINARIES_0_BINARY_0:FOURSTAR_2BINARIES_1_BINARY_1:FOURSTAR_2BINARIES_0_BINARY_1:NONE:THREESTAR_BINARYPLUSONE_BINARY_0:THREESTAR_BINARYPLUSONE_BINARY_1:THREESTAR_BINARYPLUSONE_2
indexReactBuild8.html:377 working U and V:2 2
react-dom.development.js:14894 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {myComponent}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in label (created by ClusterSelection)
    in form (created by ClusterSelection)
    in ClusterSelection (created by AjaxProcess)
    in AjaxProcess (created by NameProcess)
    in NameProcess (created by NameForm)
    in NameForm
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:14894)
    at createChild (react-dom.development.js:15127)
    at reconcileChildrenArray (react-dom.development.js:15378)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:15744)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:18235)
    at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:18757)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:20339)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:330)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:379)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:434)

Updated code

```
                class ClusterSelection extends React.Component {
                  /*1*/
                  constructor(props) {
                    /*2*/
                    super(props);
                    this.state = {
                      /*3*/
                      theProps: this.props.value,
                      error: null,
                      isLoaded: false,
                      items: '',
                      value: ''
                    };
                    /* 3 */

                    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
                    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
                  }
                  /* 2 */


                  handleChange(event) {
                    this.setState({
                      value: event.target.value
                    });
                  }

                  handleSubmit(event) {
                    alert('first choice is: ' + this.state.value);
                    event.preventDefault();
                  }

                  componentDidMount() {
                    /* 2 */
                    fetch("http://www.localhost:8080/johntredden-1.0/userDesignatedSubCluster.html").then(res => res.json()).then(result => {
                      /* 3 */
                      this.setState({
                        /* 4 */
                        isLoaded: true,
                        items: result
                      });
                      /* 4 */
                      // alert("items:"+ result);
                    },
                    /* 3 */
                    // Note: it's important to handle errors here
                    // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
                    // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
                    error => {
                      /* 3 */
                      this.setState({
                        /* 4 */
                        isLoaded: true,
                        error
                      });
                      /* 4 */
                    });
                    /* 3 */
                  }
                  /* 2 */


                  render() {
                    /* 2 */
                    const {
                      error,
                      isLoaded,
                      items
                    } = this.state;

                    if (error) {
                      return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", null, "Error: ", error.message);
                    } else if (!isLoaded) {
                      return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", null, "Loading cluster selection ...");
                    } else {
                      var response = parseJson.parseStart(this.state.items);
                      var clusterTypes = response.split(':');
                      var data = [];

                      for (var i = 1; i < clusterTypes.length; i++) {
                        data[i] = clusterTypes[i];
                      }

                      const myComponent = () => /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("select", {
                        options: data,
                        onChange: this.handleChange
                      });

                      console.log("working U and V:" + this.state.theProps.getUdim() + " " + this.state.theProps.getVdim()); // print_recursive(this.state.theProps);       

                      return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("form", {
                        onSubmit: this.handleSubmit
                      }, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("label", null, "select cluster type:", {
                        myComponent
                      }, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("input", {
                        type: "submit",
                        value: "Submit"
                      })));
                    }
                  }
                  /* 2 */
                }
                /* 1 */
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for now, but it turns a dynamic list into a static list.  It introduces a dependency in the web page on the server.  I consider this to be an anti-pattern.  I still have not found an example of a dynamic Select component.

```
                class ClusterSelection extends React.Component {
                  /*1*/
                  constructor(props) {
                    /*2*/
                    super(props);
                    this.state = {
                      /*3*/
                      theProps: this.props.value,
                      error: null,
                      isLoaded: false,
                      items: "",
                      value: "",
                    };
                    /* 3 */

                    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
                    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
                  }
                  /* 2 */

                  handleChange(event) {
                    this.setState({
                      value: event.target.value,
                    });
                  }

                  handleSubmit(event) {
                    alert("first choice is: " + this.state.value);
                    event.preventDefault();
                    this.setState({
                      /* 3 */ submitted: true,
                    }); /* 3 */
                  }

                  componentDidMount() {
                    /* 2 */
                    fetch(
                      "http://www.localhost:8080/johntredden-1.0/userDesignatedSubCluster.html"
                    )
                      .then((res) => res.json())
                      .then(
                        (result) => {
                          /* 3 */
                          this.setState({
                            /* 4 */
                            isLoaded: true,
                            items: result,
                          });
                          /* 4 */
                          // alert("items:"+ result);
                        },
                        /* 3 */
                        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
                        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
                        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
                        (error) => {
                          /* 3 */
                          this.setState({
                            /* 4 */
                            isLoaded: true,
                            error,
                          });
                          /* 4 */
                        }
                      );
                    /* 3 */
                  }
                  /* 2 */

                  render() {
                    /* 2 */
                    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;

                    if (error) {
                      return /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                        "div",
                        null,
                        "Error: ",
                        error.message
                      );
                    } else if (!isLoaded) {
                      return /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                        "div",
                        null,
                        "Loading cluster selection ..."
                      );
                    } else {
                      var response = parseJson.parseStart(this.state.items);
                      var clusterTypes = response.split(":");
                      var data = [];

                      for (var i = 1; i < clusterTypes.length; i++) {
                        data[i] = clusterTypes[i];
                      }

                      //                          const myComponent = () => /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("select", {
                      //                            options: data,
                      //                            onChange: this.handleChange
                      //                          });

                      console.log(
                        "working U and V:" +
                          this.state.theProps.getUdim() +
                          " " +
                          this.state.theProps.getVdim()
                      ); // print_recursive(this.state.theProps);

                      return this.state.submitted
                        ? /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(ClusterSelectionResponse, {
                            /* 3 */ value: this.state.theProps,
                            value2: this.state.value,
                          })
                        : /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                            "form",
                            {
                              onSubmit: this.handleSubmit,
                            },
                            /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                              "label",
                              null,
                              "Select cluster configuration:",
                              /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                                "select",
                                {
                                  value: this.state.value,
                                  onChange: this.handleChange,
                                },
                                /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                                  "option",
                                  {
                                   value: " ",
                                  },
                                  "Select cluster type"
                                ),
                                /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                                  "option",
                                  {
                                    value: data[1],
                                  },
                                  data[1]
                                ),
                                /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                                  "option",
                                  {
                                    value: data[2],
                                  },
                                  data[2]
                                ),
                                /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                                  "option",
                                  {
                                    value: data[3],
                                  },
                                  data[3]
                                ),
                                /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                                  "option",
                                  {
                                    value: data[4],
                                  },
                                  data[4]
                                ),
                                /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                                  "option",
                                  {
                                    value: data[5],
                                  },
                                  data[5]
                                ),
                                /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                                  "option",
                                  {
                                    value: data[6],
                                  },
                                  data[6]
                                ),
                                /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                                  "option",
                                  {
                                    value: data[7],
                                  },
                                  data[7]
                                ),
                                /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                                  "option",
                                  {
                                    value: data[8],
                                  },
                                  data[8]
                                ),
                                /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                                  "option",
                                  {
                                    value: data[9],
                                  },
                                  data[9]
                                ),
                                /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                                  "option",
                                  {
                                    value: data[10],
                                  },
                                  data[10]
                                ),
                                /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                                  "option",
                                  {
                                    value: data[11],
                                  },
                                  data[11]
                                ),
                                /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                                  "option",
                                  {
                                    value: data[12],
                                  },
                                  data[12]
                                ),
                                /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                                  "option",
                                  {
                                    value: data[13],
                                  },
                                  data[13]
                                ),
                                /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                                  "option",
                                  {
                                    value: data[14],
                                  },
                                  data[14]
                                ),
                                /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                                  "option",
                                  {
                                    value: data[15],
                                  },
                                  data[15]
                                ),
                                /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                                  "option",
                                  {
                                    value: data[16],
                                  },
                                  data[16]
                                ),
                                /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                                  "option",
                                  {
                                    value: data[17],
                                  },
                                  data[17]
                                ),
                                /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(
                                  "option",
                                  {
                                    value: data[18],
                                  },
                                  data[18]
                                )
                              )
                            ),
                            /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement("input", {
                              type: "submit",
                              value: "Submit",
                            })
                          );
                    }
                  }
                  /* 2 */
                }
                /* 1 */
```